# How to Init a object within a CTOR after some other tasks?

Tags: c++, oop, object, initialization

I've my class `MIDITest` which got a member variable object called `IPianoRoll`:

```
class MIDITest : public IPlug 
{
private:
    IPianoRoll mPianoRoll;

public:
    MIDITest(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo);
    ~MIDITest();
};
```

I need to invoke my custom CTOR of `mPianoRoll`:

```
IPianoRoll(IPlugBase *pPlug, int x, int y, int paramIdx) : IControl(pPlug, IRECT(x, y, x + kWidth, y + kHeight), paramIdx, IChannelBlend::kBlendColorDodge) {

}
```

only after some other task within `MIDITest`, such as:

```
MIDITest::MIDITest(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo) : IPLUG_CTOR(kNumParams, kNumPresets, instanceInfo) {
    // SOME TASKS
    IGraphics *pGraphics = MakeGraphics(this, GUI_WIDTH, GUI_HEIGHT, PLUG_FPS);
    pGraphics->HandleMouseOver(true);
    AttachGraphics(pGraphics);

    // NOW I NEED TO "create it"
    mPianoRoll(this, 8, 8, kParamIDPianoRoll);
}
```

but of course I can't do `mPianoRoll(this, 8, 8, kParamIDPianoRoll);`.

I'd like to avoid pointer for this, since on "deleting" I got weird errors, and because (since I don't need pointers), I guess it's better to not use them and dynamic memory allocation.

I can't use Member Init List, since it will be called/used before the Task within the `MIDITest` CTOR.

What's the way?

Comment: The code you show doesn't actually of anything that the construction of `mPianoRoll` depends on, as far as I can see. Perhaps `kParamIDPianoRoll` whatever that is?

Comment: I don't understand. [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the construction of `mPianoRoll` depends on some of the "tasks" that you perform in the constructor, then you could simply use the assignment operator and do e.g.

```
mPianoRoll = IPianoRoll(this, 8, 8, kParamIDPianoRoll);
```

Another possible solution is to make the "tasks" separate classes and have instances of them in the `MIDITest` class or have `MIDITest` inherit from them (as [*mixins*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)), and use the construction initializer list for all initialization and tasks, ending with the `mPianoRoll` construction in the list.

Comment: I like the first way. But when I try, it says `'IControl': no appropriate default constructor available`. Because `class IPianoRoll : public IControl` I guess. `IControl` is from a framework, I can't touch it. What should I add?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the *other tasks* into a base class. Base classes constructors will get processed first.

You could as well move them into a function, make it return a value, and use it to explicitly initialize another member in the initialization list.

Otherwise, it seems the *other tasks* are something the member variable is dependant upon, hence it may make sense to move it inside that member variable, or inside a wrapper object (that would be then normally initialized).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to initialize `mPianoRoll` with as much information as you have in  initializer list and then update its state in the body of the constructor.

```
MIDITest::MIDITest(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo) : IPLUG_CTOR(kNumParams, kNumPresets, instanceInfo),
                                                     mPianoRoll(this, 8, 8, <not sure what this would be> {
    // SOME TASKS
    IGraphics *pGraphics = MakeGraphics(this, GUI_WIDTH, GUI_HEIGHT, PLUG_FPS);
    pGraphics->HandleMouseOver(true);
    AttachGraphics(pGraphics);

    // update the state of mPianoRoll.
    mPianoRoll->someSetFunction(kParamIDPianoRoll);
}
```